# Using QT Tree Model with Custom data

Tags: qt, qt5

This is my Header file for Container object.

```
class Container
 {
   private:
   std::string stdstrContainerName;
   std::string stdstrPluginType;
   int iSegments;
   float fRadius;

 public:
     Container();
     Container(std::string , std::string ,  int , float);
     Container(const  Container& obj);  
     ~Container();
     std::string GetName();
     std::string GetType();
     void SetName(std::string stdstrName);
  };
   Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( Container )
```

I use Container as the datatype in TreeItem.

```
class TreeItem
 {
   public:
       explicit TreeItem( const Container &data , TreeItem *parent = 0 );
       ~TreeItem();
       TreeItem *parent();
       TreeItem *child(int iNumber);
       int childCount() const;
       int childNumber() const;
       Container data() const;
       bool setData(const Container &data);
       bool insertChildren(int position, int count );
       bool removeChildren( int position  , int count );

  private:
       QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
       Container itemData;
       TreeItem* parentItem;
  };
```

The problem is that when i add rows to the Tree Structure the rows gets added but with no text on them.
I want to set the data in stdstrContainerName as the data on the row.

if i try to write something it does not stay.

i think the problem is with my functions which set the data to TreeItem object

```
  Container TreeItem::data() const
   {
      return itemData;
    }

    bool TreeItem::setData(const Container &data , QVariant value )
      {
        itemData = data;
        itemData.SetName(value.toString().toStdString() );
        return true;
     }
```

/

Data Function for Tree Model

```
  QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
  {
    if (!index.isValid())
    return QVariant();

      if (role != Qt::DisplayRole && role != Qt::EditRole)
        return QVariant();

       TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
         return QString::fromStdString(item->data().GetName());
  }

  bool TreeModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &val, int 
  role )
  {
     if (role != Qt::EditRole)
       return false;

      Container c = val.value<Container>();
      TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
      bool result = item->setData(c);

     if (result)
      emit dataChanged(index, index, { role });

     return result;
 }
```

I can also post any additional code of the project.

Comment: How is your tree model's `data()` function looks like?

Comment: @vahancho i  have updated the code with Tree Model data functions.

Comment: I think you should return the concrete data from your `Container` object instead of converting it to `QVariant`, i.e. `return QString::fromStdString(item->data().GetName());`

Comment: In `setData()` you should construct a `Container` object from the value and set it to the tree item.

Comment: I have been able to get the  treemodel working but , how do i retrieve the container object from the selected  row in the tree view.

Comment: You need to get a model index from the selected row, than get tree item by that index from the tree model and from the tree item get its container.

Answer (score 0):

What's missing here is the code of your view.

A `QAbstractItemView` derived view cannot display `Container` `QVariant`s by itself.

- **Either** you implement your view in such a way that it

  - interprets `Container-QVariant`s and displays e.g. its `GetName()`
  - provides an editor that can manipulate `Container-QVariant`s
- **or** (*simpler method*) you shift the concretion layer into your model and

  - return `item->GetName()`, `->GetType()` depending on `role` and `index.column()`
  - manipulate the `Container` instance in the `TreeItem` from the text passed in `QVariant val`

Comment: I have been able to get the treemodel working but , how do i retrieve the container object from the selected row in the tree view